# Replace text of a div which contain a <span> with icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

I want to replace the whole text of a div but not remove the `span` inside it.

I have to replace the text in the following div ("Yourself") once the user clicks on some element in the `ul`:

```
<div style="display: inline">
    <div class="text-light" style="float: left">Post as: </div>
    <div class="link toggle-post" style="float: right" >
        Yourself
        <span id="dropdownIcon" class="ui-icon-dropdown"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the following code:

```
$('[data-postas]').click(function changeHeader(event){
    var element = $(event.srcElement);
    $('.toggle-post').text().replace($('.toggle-post').text(), element.text());
    $('#postAs').val(element.attr('data-postas'));
    if (element.attr('data-company')){
        $('#company').val(element.attr('data-company'));
    }

    $('.icon-cheack').remove();
    element.append('<i class="icon-cheack fright"></i>');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".ul-post").toggle();
    }, 500);
    $('#dropdownIcon').addClass('ui-icon-dropdown');
})
```

The text is not replaced

Comment: save a reference of the span before you replace the entire div content, then reappend the span

Comment: Another idea would be to put "Yourself" into a separate `<span>` so you can just remove the content of that one.

Answer (score 1):

As @BeNdErR sad, save the `span`, put the `icon`, add back the `span`:

```
//Save the old one
var span = $('#dropdownIcon');
//Empty the div
$('.toggle-post').empty().append('<i class="icon-cheack fright"></i>').append(span);
```

Comment: I found an answer which can be relevant, and I edit the question. Unfortunately it's not working :( Why?

Comment: I am not seeing any relevant code edition. But you can check this, use inspect element to check, div content has been replaced.

Comment: Foget the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/yan91mrg/

Comment: No, it's not, there is it in the append `<i class="icon-cheack fright"></i>` This is just a demonstration, of course, you do not see the icon, because there are no images, and css for it. But as I sad, if you see with inspect element, you will se it is there.

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
var sp = $('.toggle-post span.ui-icon-dropdown'); 
$('.toggle-post').html( "text to replace").append(sp);
```